# If ever partial derivative is zero then the function is continuous?

Tags: calculus

I am solving the problem about if every single partial derivative is zero for a hole open set and for every unitary directional vector. Then f:$\Bbb R^n \rightarrow \Bbb R$ is constant. But my problem doesnt lie in there. My problem is that too many people use the mean theorem value, but what I cannot figure out is that one of its hypothesis implie to show that your function f is continuous in a certain interval. But I dont know how to show it, first, we are talking about only one linear direction to study the function, so continuity implied moving in any direction and only it could be differentiable if the partial are continuous, but again, to show that the partial are continuous implie infromation about getting near a certain point in EVERY single direction. How can I show the existant of continuity in f?

Comment: If the partial derivatives are all identically zero on an open set, they are continuous there, hence $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: Hint: Take a look at the definition of a derivative.  What does that imply?

Comment: But why are they continuous, I can only show a kind of continuity in the direction of the vector where i am making the derivation. But that doesnt implie movement in other directions, only in a linear way. And thats what a directional derivative definition implie. Linear movements.

Comment: @Mounice You were already told: if the partial derivatives of first order exist and all but one of them is continuous then the function is **differentiable**, so the directional derivatives *in any direction* on any points of that open set exist and are given by the scalar product of the function's gradient and the unit vector in the wanted direction. So you only need the existence of the part. deriv. and they're zero. That the directional derivatives exist follows from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are examples of discontinuous functions $f: \mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R$ for which all partial derivatives exist.

We need to use the fact that not only do the partial derivatives exist, but they are zero.

To do this we must first prove that $f$ is constant among every line parallel to one of the coordinate axis.

In other words, given any vector $(x_1,x_2,\dots x_{n-1})$ let $g:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be defined by $g(x)=f(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_{n-1},x)$. By hypothesis this function has derivative zero in each point. So it is continuous, and by the mean value theorem must be a constant function.

Therefore, if two vectors coincide in all variables except the last, then they are equal under $f$. You can prove in a very similar fashion that for any $i$,if we have to vectors that are equal in all entries except the $i$'th entry then hey are equal under $f$.

Therefore, given two vectors $(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n)$ and $(y_1,y_2,\dots, y_n)$ we have:

$f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)=f(y_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)=f(y_1,y_2,x_3,\dots,x_n)=\dots=f(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n)$

---

Edit: you can make the argument shorter by noticing that every partial derivative is continuous (since it's constant). It follows that $f$ is differentiable, and you can now apply the mean value theorem directly.

Comment: Well I had a similar idea, about showing that in every direction the kind of function that lied in the cut plane was constant, and do it for every direction and with a mean value theorem for several varibales show that every image for the elements of my open set had the same value. But as you pointed out when you made the g function an use the mean valued theorem for one dimension you used for hypothesis that you g was continuous in a certain interval, and with that tha f was continuous. But that what i dont understand where it is show that f is continuous?

Comment: Im not saying that the theorem is incorrect Im just not understand or rahter seeing my problem.

Comment: So tell me if what I say is correct, i can consider the partial derivatives as functions such as p:$\Bbb R^n \rightarrow \Bbb R$  and (tell me here) every contant function from $\Bbb R^n \rightarrow \Bbb R$ is continuous, then specially the partial are continuous and becuase they exist, then f is differentiable?